# Android MapView getting corrupted after lengthy use

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have an android application with a MapView in it, and it runs pretty much continuously for hours at a time with minimal user interaction on users' phones.  I've found that after a while, something can happen to the MapView that makes it become completely unusable.

The application doesn't crash, and the map is still there, but it seems to be corrupted.  Pinching/scrolling the map causes the tiles to jolt and fly around, and the markers to bounce around at random.  Does this sound like something anyone has encountered?

edit: the following code runs about once every 10 seconds:

```
public void updateMarkers(boolean centerMap) 
{
    log("updateMarkers(" + centerMap + ")");
    int vehicLat = (int) (AppState.getLatitude() * 1e6);
    int vehicLng = (int) (AppState.getLongitude() * 1e6);
    GeoPoint vehiclePoint = new GeoPoint(vehicLat, vehicLng);

    List<Overlay> currentOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    if(!currentOverlays.isEmpty()) 
    { 
        currentOverlays.clear();
        mapView.postInvalidate();
    }

    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car);
    MapOverlay iconOverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable, this);
    OverlayItem iconPoint = new OverlayItem(vehiclePoint, "", "");
    iconOverlay.addOverlay(iconPoint);
    currentOverlays.add(iconOverlay);

    if(centerMap)
    {
        mapController.setCenter(vehiclePoint);
        mapController.setZoom(17);
    }


    mapView.postInvalidate();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing? I have large app that uses a map view (for long periods) and I don't see this behavior

Comment: its basically a map that shows the user's current location, and occasionally has a few markers on it.  This problem only seems to occur after extended use

Comment: Some code would be helpful...

Comment: ok, postd the update map code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the bug is in that section of code, the problem is likely:

```
 Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car);
 MapOverlay iconOverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable, this);
```

You're making a zillion drawable objects when you really only need 1. In my experience with Android, the garbage collection on drawables (and Bitmaps) is pretty poor (if you read about it enough, you'll begin to wonder if it's actually broken...). Here's what I'd do:

1. Pull the drawable once in the class. Store the drawable -- don't pull it every 10 seconds.
2. Before you clear the list of currentOverlays, set the drawable on each thing to `null`.

Example:

```
List<Overlay> currentOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
if(!currentOverlays.isEmpty()) 
{ 
  for(Overlay o : currentOverlays)
  {
      // You need to a typecast here I think
      o.setDrawable(null);
  }
  currentOverlays.clear();    
  mapView.postInvalidate();
}
```

Comment: very interesting, I didn't know that about drawables.  I'll try this out now, thank you!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more.  Spent half the day trying to figure out why I was getting "bitmap size exceeds VM budget" crashes.  This seems to have fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: This change to the code eliminates the crash bug "bitmap size exceeds VM budget", which is very helpful.  I am still however seeing my original problem every so often, and cannot see an error in the log when it occurs.  I wish i could post a video!

Comment: Could be all the `postInvalidates` queuing up in some weird way. Try to call `postInvalidate` only once in that function (right now it looks like you call it twice). Also might have to reduce calls to `setCenter` and `setZoom` -- perhaps by figuring out if you really need to that (ie. look at position first, see if it is close enough.)

Comment: Also you might could do something where if the map isn't actually visible (ie. phone is asleep), you could skip the whole method. When the phone wakes up again simply do the method once at that time. Google "Android Activity Lifecycle" -- look at using `onPause()` and `onResume()` to figure out when your app is going in/out of focus.